# Flexi Auth Demo + Codeigniter not working on Xampp Localhost

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, authentication, xampp

I installed flexi auth demo on my online website & it works fine.

But I have problem on localhost. I want to customize it & for that I need to work on localhost. I have following settings: local host with CI + XAMPP + Windows 7

Directory structure:

```
http://localhost/xampp/prj/pub    <- Here I have index.php & .htaccess file
http://localhost/xampp/prj/main/system      <- This is CI System folder
http://localhost/xampp/prj/main/application <- This is CI Application folder
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /prj/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

I use [http://localhost/xampp/prj/pub] to access the flexi auth demo & it opens main page. But when i click “Try the Demo” it takes me to xampp default web root i.e. [http://localhost/xampp] & shows directory listing of this folder.

I have been checking by changing base path & different .htaccess parameters but no success. At present I have set my base url : [http://localhost/xampp/prj/pub/] in auth_lite.php file.

I think the problem is in .htaccess or settings of xampp need to be changed.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your prj folder out of the `xampp` directory so that is a subdirectory of the `htdocs` folder.  Then you can access it via `http://localhost/prj`

You may also need to alter the `base_url` in the config file: application/config/config.php

Any errors can be found in the php/logs directory of your xampp root.

Answer (score 0):

in config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

change it to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

in codignater Framework